# Stop a download from appearing on chrome download bar

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Chrome Extension and I'm using this code to "catch" a download on request.

```
chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener(function(downloadItem) {

});
```

What I want is to stop the download from appearing on the download bar, read the file in my extension and then delete the file from the computer.

I've tried using chrome.extensions.download.erase() and chrome.browsingData.remove() but to no avail.

How can I do this?

Comment: Try to catch the download before, for example, when the user clicks on the link, cancel the event and download the file from your background page.

Comment: @Gael could you write a simple example? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a content script:

```
document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click",function(){
 chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "download", url: this.href});
});
```

//may be you should restrict the selector to the specific links that you want to download with your extension.

In a background page:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.action == "download" ){
      //here download via xhr, then read the file as you plan to do 
    }
});
```

Comment: I think a `webRequest`-based approach is going to be more solid than hooking to `<a>` links only.

Comment: The downloading part of this worked. But tbh, I think I'm in a bit to deep for my skill level. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 5):

A better event is `onDeterminingFilename`, since this happens before the download starts:

```
chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(function (item) {
    chrome.downloads.cancel(item.id);
});
```

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#event-onDeterminingFilename