# how to disable download progress bar in chrome

Tags: html, node.js, express, pdf, blob

[image]I'm building a website using express and ejs. I'm building chart using chartjs in a canvas and taking the image (downloading) using blob and file saver. I'm using this image to make a pdf with some data from database. My problem is i'm genrating and downloading the pdf in another button click. and saving the image in another button click. but on each click the chrome download bar is showing up. how to disable it?

Regards.

Comment: what's a chrome download bar?

Comment: the download progress tab we see on bottom of our window while we download something?

Comment: is that a MS Windows thing? Do you have a screenshot? It would help if you added some code. If your fetching a blob using ajax there shouldn't be any indication its "downloading", if you mean you see a prompt to download then your not doing it right if you want the blob into js

Comment: no google chrome

Comment: Yeah, it looks like your code is downloading it (and you have checked to not ask/prompt again). If you want to use the image inside js then you fetch it with ajax. Will need to see your code to help further.

Comment: have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782228/stop-a-download-from-appearing-on-chrome-download-bar) ?